# What's wrong with my IF/ELSE? "ELSE: Incorrect syntax near 'ELSE'."

Tags: sql-server, ssis

I have code similar to this:

```
DECLARE @IdentificationNumber INT
DECLARE @Foreign_ID BIGINT

IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [main-table] WHERE [identification-number] = @IdentificationNumber) > 0)

    SET @Foreign_ID = (SELECT [Foreign_ID] FROM [main-table] WHERE [identification-number] = @IdentificationNumber) 

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [main-table]
        SET [column1] = '', [column2] = '', [column3] = ''
        WHERE [Foreign_ID] = @Foreign_ID
    END

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [table2]
        SET [column4] = '', [column5] = '', [column6] = ''
        WHERE [Foreign_ID] = @Foreign_ID
    END

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [table3] 
        SET [column7] = '', [column8] = '', [column9] = ''
        WHERE [Foreign_ID] = @Foreign_ID
    END
    -- and so on, up to 14

ELSE -- "Incorrect syntax near 'ELSE'.

    BEGIN
        INSERT into ... -- blah blah blah. 
    END
```

...but I get an error while trying to use `ELSE`: `Incorrect syntax near 'ELSE'.`

Comment: You do realize that you're taking a procedural approach to SQL, correct? Generally speaking, you're better off using a set based approach

Comment: I didn't know much about SQL until a couple months ago. Could you show me a better method, please?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Answer (score 20, accepted):

`IF - Else` syntax is

```
If condition
begin
--statement
end
else 
begin
--statement
end
```

In your query after First `IF statement` you bunch of `Begin - End` statements all those has to be wrapped inside a `Begin - End` . Like

```
IF ((SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [main-table] WHERE [identification-number] = @IdentificationNumber) > 0)
Begin -- Missing
    SET @Foreign_ID = (SELECT [Foreign_ID] FROM [main-table] WHERE [identification-number] = @IdentificationNumber) 

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [main-table]
        SET [column1] = '', [column2] = '', [column3] = ''
        WHERE [Foreign_ID] = @Foreign_ID
    END

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [table2]
        SET [column4] = '', [column5] = '', [column6] = ''
        WHERE [Foreign_ID] = @Foreign_ID
    END

    BEGIN
        UPDATE [table3] 
        SET [column7] = '', [column8] = '', [column9] = ''
        WHERE [Foreign_ID] = @Foreign_ID
    END
END -- Missing
else
....
```

Comment: How on earth did I miss that? Pretty funny. Thanks! I'm gonna give it a go and see how it works. If it's good enough, I'll accept your answer. :-)